# Linq to SQL, InsertOnSubmit vs. InsertAllOnSubmit performance?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Is there a huge difference in performance between the two, for instance I have these two code snippets:

```
public void Insert(IEnumerable<ManageGeofenceViewModel> geofences)
{
    var insertGeofences = new List<Geofence>();

    foreach(var geofence in geofences)
    {
        Geofence insertGeofence = new Geofence
        {
            name = geofence.Name,
            radius = geofence.Meters,
            latitude = geofence.Latitude,
            longitude = geofence.Longitude,
            custom_point_type_id = geofence.CategoryID
        };

        insertGeofences.Add(insertGeofence);

    }

    this.context.Geofences.InsertAllOnSubmit(insertGeofences);
    this.context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

vs

```
public void Insert(IEnumerable<ManageGeofenceViewModel> geofences)
{
    foreach(var geofence in geofences)
    {
        Geofence insertGeofence = new Geofence
        {
            name = geofence.Name,
            radius = geofence.Meters,
            latitude = geofence.Latitude,
            longitude = geofence.Longitude,
            custom_point_type_id = geofence.CategoryID
        };
        this.context.Geofences.InsertOnSubmit(insertGeofence);
    }
    this.context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Which among the two is better and does the two code snippet have the same number of trips to the database since in the 1st snippet submitchanges was called outside of the loop?

Comment: You can easily check it by yourself adding a logging mechanism to your `context`: http://damieng.com/blog/2008/07/30/linq-to-sql-log-to-debug-window-file-memory-or-multiple-writers

Comment: As far as I know, the InsertAllOnSubmit only iterates over a IEnumerable an calls InsertOnSubmit for each element. The important thing to call SubmitChanges inside or outside the loop, because each SubmitChanges call opens a new transaction/connection.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no difference at all, InsertAllOnSubmit actually calls the InsertOnSubmit, here is the code for InsertAllSubmit:

```
public void InsertAllOnSubmit<TSubEntity>(IEnumerable<TSubEntity> entities) where TSubEntity : TEntity
{
    if (entities == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("entities");
    }
    this.CheckReadOnly();
    this.context.CheckNotInSubmitChanges();
    this.context.VerifyTrackingEnabled();
    List<TSubEntity> list = entities.ToList<TSubEntity>();
    using (List<TSubEntity>.Enumerator enumerator = list.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            TEntity entity = (TEntity)((object)enumerator.Current);
            this.InsertOnSubmit(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see InsertAllOnSubmit is just a handy wrapper around InsertOnSubmit

Answer (score -1):

You can find lot of convenient methods like this which focuses on coding efficiency. If you have a List of entities which you want to insert in to a Database at once, you can use `InsertAllOnSubmit`. Following is an example from one of my projects.

```
public void InsertAll(IEnumerable<MyClass> list)
    {
        DataContext.MyClasses.InsertAllOnSubmit<MyClass>(list);
        DataContext.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

This code enables me to add multiple entities to the DataContext using one line. After adding I can submit the changes in one go, avoiding any multiple database calls.